# Dokuwiki on a stick - how to put microapache server in background

Tags: dokuwiki

Does anyone know, while using [DokuWiki on stick](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki_on_a_stick), how to put the Apache microserver *in the background*, that is remove it from the taskbar without actually shutting it down.

I wish to be able to access the Wiki via *localhost*, but don't want to have an open application down in the taskbar all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VBScript to run mapache.exe in hidden window.

In DokuWikiStick root create file run.vbs, fill it with

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("mapache.exe"),0
```

and use it to run your DokuWikiStick server.

Unfortunatelly there is a problem with stopping server started this way, because there is no window to close. You can use Task Manager to terminate mapache.exe processes.